# Attaching a model immediately after creation with firstOrCreate

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm working on an application in which i can store a band, which has one or more genres. First i create the band. Next i'm looping over the selected genres, and only create a new genre if it doesn't exists in my database. This works great. But when i try to attach the newly added genre to the band, it attaches the first genre in my database (which has id 1), instead of the new one.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $band =  Band::create($request->merge([
        'owner_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ])->all());

    foreach($request->genres as $genre_name){
        $genre = Genre::firstOrCreate(['name' => $genre_name])->save();
        $band->genres()->attach($genre);
    }

    return redirect()->route('bands.index')->withStatus(__('Band successfully created'));
}
```

The new genres are added without any problems, so it would seem like the 'firstOrCreate' works correctly. But the returned $genre is not correct.

My Band table :

```
 Schema::create('bands', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->unsignedInteger('owner_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My Genres table :

```
Schema::create('genres', function (Blueprint $table) {;
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The pivot table :

```
Schema::create('band_genres', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('band_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('genre_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('band_id')->references('id')->on('bands')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('genre_id')->references('id')->on('genres')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And the relationship in the band model :

```
/*
* Get genres
*/
public function genres() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Genre', 'band_genres', 'band_id', 'genre_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

So i added a new band, with a new genre. The new genre was added succesfully with id 7. But when i check the genres for the new band it shows a connection with genre 1?

```
+----+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | band_id | genre_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 | 2020-06-10 18:15:56 | 2020-06-10 18:15:56 |
+----+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've looked at this for hours, but i can't see it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `save()` after `firstOrCreate()`. Remove the call to `save()`.

First, there's no reason to call `save()`. `firstOrCreate()` with either return an existing model or create a new model that is already saved to the database.

Second, `save()` returns a boolean, so your `$genre` variable is getting set to `true`. You're then passing that into `attach()`, where it gets turned into an integer id (int 1).

Comment: That's it, thank you very much. I'm quite confused because the documentation states : The firstOrNew method, like firstOrCreate will attempt to locate a record in the database matching the given attributes. However, if a model is not found, a new model instance will be returned. Note that the model returned by firstOrNew has not yet been persisted to the database. **You will need to call save manually to persist it**

Comment: @TimCreemers If you had used `firstOrNew()`, you'd need to manually save the new instance to persist it in the database. However, you used `firstOrCreate()`, which automatically saves the new instance to the database.

Comment: Ok i see now, misread the docs. Thanks for pointing out the issue!